# Some misunderstanding using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this html code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the view I get the following result:

[image]

The desired view result is:

[image]

The HTML code above I took is from this [site](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic).

Any idea why my view is different from the desired view?

Comment: Are you sure you are adding the Bootstrap CSS?

Answer (score 3):

It'll work **if you got enough width for them**

> **[Bootstrap Doc #grid-options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) :**
>
> Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)

Resize your windows or try to use

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u8w7fca6/3/

Answer (score 2):

The columns will stack vertically I there is not room to display them all horizontally. If you increase the width of the browser window they should revert to being inline.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xm-12 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
    <p>Try this</p>
    </div>
</div>
```